# Get list of chats in Skype

Tags: c#, .net, skype4com

I just have tried to get list of chats and I am not able to get it.

```
from Chat chat in _skype.chats select new Chat
```

It doesn't include all chats. I have create new one and can't see it in list.

Comment: _skype = new Skype();
_skype.Attach();

Answer (score 0):

This will show all chats, including hidden ones.  For this reason, you may see duplicates of chats with *single contacts* only.

```
Imports SKYPE4COMLib

Public Class Form1
Dim skype As Skype

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    For Each r As Chat In skype.Chats
        'If topic = "", then it is an individual chat
        If r.Topic <> "" Then
            RichTextBox1.AppendText(r.Topic & vbCrLf)
        Else
            'If topic = "", then display the FriendlyName instead (individual chat)
            RichTextBox1.AppendText(r.FriendlyName & vbCrLf)
        End If

    Next
End Sub

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    skype = New Skype()
    skype.Attach(7, True)
End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: This does NOT show all chats. I am a member of at least 6 chats, with recent messages (last day or so), that are not found by this code. Many of my chats are found but not all of them.

Comment: Oops!  Thanks for this, I only had a few group chats and they all showed up.  I did some digging, and I found that the group names are stored under the DisplayName property within the Conversations table in the main.db file, but currently I see no way to access this with the Skype API.

Comment: This makes me sad ... I had hoped to develop a little script that would set my chats to /alertsoff at night and /alertson in the morning. But it doesn't look like it's going to happen.

Comment: Ross Presser, could you instead make a script to turn your profile to "Do not disturb" at night and "Online" in the morning?  Would this accomplish what you want?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I'll look into it. I actually accomplished what I wanted with an autohotkey script that simulates mouse and keypresses.